Problem with overlapping inputs for Price Slider on FireFox
Right now my price slider works great on chrome, safari and edge, but on firefox, even though I've made specific adjustments, one of the sliders appears to be under the other one, causing it to be useless.Firefox, Chrome
I've tried different solutions but none have worked, including changing the z-index and so forth. I read that firefox handles overlapping inputs differently, so I'm wondering if there's a solution?
HTML:
<div class="range-slider" id="range-slider">
                <span class="rangeValues" id="range-values"></span>
                <input value="0" min="0" max="100" step="1" type="range" class="range-input">
                <input value="100" min="0" max="100" step="1" type="range" class="range-input">
              </div>

CSS:
.range-slider {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.range-input {
  border-radius: 100vh;
}

.range-slider .rangeValues {
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: var(--text-color);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none; /* Firefox compatibility */
  appearance: none; /* General compatibility */
  border: none;
  width: 100%; /* Ensure the range fills the slider */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: var(--text-color);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100vh;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 100vh;
  background: var(--hover-color);
  margin-top: -6.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Firefox track styling */
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  height: 5px; /* Match WebKit track height */
  background: var(--text-color);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100vh;
}

/* Firefox thumb styling */
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 100vh;
  background: var(--hover-color);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

input[type="range"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="range"]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type="range"]:focus::-moz-range-track {
  background: #ccc;
}


The standard trick is to raise the z-index of the first thumb and progress so that both are above the second track and progress. The bad news is that, sadly, it cannot be done as easily as styling the slider. Bugzilla 1663819 is about 4 years old. The most recent activity was to close Bugzilla 1841723, opened and closed 1 year ago, as a duplicate. Apparently making the range inflexible fixed some other problem, but caused this one.
